# Inner join and group by

Tags: join, ssms, group-by

So I've got two tables.

Accounts has three columns:

```
id, Account_ID, Account_Name
```

Tickets also has three columns:

```
id, Account_ID, Description
```

I can use the following query to get the most commonly occurring account IDs from within the ticket table - The accounts which are the most active in submitting tickets

```
select account_id, count(*) as 'occurences' from tickets group by account_id order by occurences desc
```

which is great, but i'd like to group that on the accounts table so the output reads

```
Accounts.Account_Name, Count of occurences from previous query
```

I tried [this codeplex example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/57496/SQL-Group-by-With-Joins) to no avail, I get the error

```
The multi-part identifier "ticket.Account_ID" could not be bound.
```

using this query

```
Select accounts.Account_Name, Accounts.Account_ID, TotalTickets
from Accounts  
inner join 
(Select tickets.Account_ID,count(*) as TotalTickets
from  Tickets group by ticket.Account_ID) acctTickets 
on acctTickets.Account_ID= accounts.Account_ID
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your table is named `tickets` but you've aliased it `ticket.Account_ID` in the inner join Group By, hence the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select ac.Account_Name, ac.Account_ID, count(t.ID) as 'Total Tickets'
from accounts ac
join tickets t on
ac.Account_ID = t.Account_ID
group by ac.account_ID, ac.account_name
```

I think the only error in your query is that you aliased "tickets" as "ticket", but your query is also more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: I can't believe I missed it, but whatever. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, Now that I'm back at my desk, I tried fixing my typo, now I get the error `Column 'dbo.tickets.Account_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: And when I try your solution: `Column 'accounts.Account_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: I edited it, add ac.account_name to the group by list.

Comment: That works. Thank you and I apologize for the noobishness. I'm just a mere mortal programmer!